# SDL2 Window is created but not shown

Tags: c, sdl-2

Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(){
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0){
        return -1;
    }

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN|SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);

    if(window){
        SDL_Delay(3000);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    }
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

The window is created and I manage to get in the if statement, it just doesn't show the window.

I'm working on VSCode, on Ubuntu (which I installed today, so there might be components I'm missing for the window to show but as of right now I don't know).

Comment: Try adding an event loop (look up `SDL_PollEvents()`).

Comment: Window is shown fine, but it is empty and transparent. It's not filled with anything. The only thing that displays is the window decoration painted by your window manager.

Comment: I already tried an event loop and it doesn't work. When I say the window doesn't show up it's because I tested it on another machine and it works fine (it shows a black window with nothing, but at least a window is shown), here it just doesn't show anything

Comment: have you tried `SDL_ShowWindow` ?

Comment: Yes I tried it even though it should already be shown with the SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN parameter in the SDL_CreateWindow function. Still doesn't show the window